# my code is not running in webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I am running a simple code to open google.co.uk in a firefox broswer but after the running the code in eclipse, it only opens up the browser stops there. Please help. Here's the code-

```
package basic_webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Driver_Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? What OS?

Comment: What kind of exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk/");
```

The Navigate function tells the browser to navigate somewhere.
The GoToURL function indicates that the browser should navigate to a specific URL.
The string for the URL is input as a parameter for the GoToURL.

The above should make the browser navigate to a specific URL.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?